# Dart migration tool errors on generated files

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use `dart migrate` to upgrade dart to null safety, but when I do, I get tons of errors in my generated files:

```
benjaminfarquhar@Benjamins-MacBook-Pro vepo_front_end % dart migrate                        
Warning: `dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety` exited with exit code 69 and stderr:

Package doesn't exist (the Flutter SDK is not available).

Migrating /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end

Note: more than one project found; migrating the top-level project.

Analyzing project...
[-                                                                                                                             [----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/]
82 analysis issues found:
  error • Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_data/flutter_data.dart' at lib/main.data.dart:4:8 • (uri_does_not_exist)
  error • Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:provider/provider.dart' at lib/main.data.dart:7:8 • (uri_does_not_exist)
  error • Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:provider/single_child_widget.dart' at lib/main.data.dart:8:8 • (uri_does_not_exist)
  error • Undefined class 'ConfigureRepositoryLocalStorage' at lib/main.data.dart:10:1 • (undefined_class)
  error • Undefined class 'FutureFn' at lib/main.data.dart:11:7 • (undefined_class)
  error • Undefined name 'hiveLocalStorageProvider' at lib/main.data.dart:15:10 • (undefined_identifier)
  error • Undefined name 'RiverpodAlias' at lib/main.data.dart:15:56 • (undefined_identifier)
  error • Missing parameter type for '_' at lib/main.data.dart:16:8 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • The function 'HiveLocalStorage' isn't defined at lib/main.data.dart:16:14 • (undefined_function)
  error • Undefined class 'RepositoryInitializerProvider' at lib/main.data.dart:20:1 • (undefined_class)
  error • The function 'RepositoryInitializerArgs' isn't defined at lib/main.data.dart:23:7 • (undefined_function)
  error • Missing variable type for '_repositoryInitializerProviderFamily' at lib/main.data.dart:26:7 • (implicit_dynamic_variable)
  error • Undefined name 'RiverpodAlias' at lib/main.data.dart:26:46 • (undefined_identifier)
  error • The name 'RepositoryInitializer' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument at lib/main.data.dart:27:5 • (non_type_as_type_argument)
  error • The name 'RepositoryInitializerArgs' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument at lib/main.data.dart:27:28 • (non_type_as_type_argument)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'ref' at lib/main.data.dart:27:56 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'args' at lib/main.data.dart:27:61 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • The name 'RemoteAdapter' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument at lib/main.data.dart:28:39 • (non_type_as_type_argument)
  error • The function 'RepositoryInitializer' isn't defined at lib/main.data.dart:30:10 • (undefined_function)
  error • The name 'SingleChildWidget' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument at lib/main.data.dart:33:6 • (non_type_as_type_argument)
  error • Undefined class 'FutureFn' at lib/main.data.dart:34:6 • (undefined_class)
  error • Missing type argument for list literal at lib/main.data.dart:39:10 • (implicit_dynamic_list_literal)
  error • Missing parameter type for '_' at lib/main.data.dart:41:16 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • The function 'ProviderContainer' isn't defined at lib/main.data.dart:41:22 • (undefined_function)
  error • Missing type argument for list literal at lib/main.data.dart:41:51 • (implicit_dynamic_list_literal)
  error • The name 'RepositoryInitializer' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument at lib/main.data.dart:46:22 • (non_type_as_type_argument)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'context' at lib/main.data.dart:47:16 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing variable type for 'init' at lib/main.data.dart:48:15 • (implicit_dynamic_variable)
  error • The name 'ProviderContainer' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument at lib/main.data.dart:49:33 • (non_type_as_type_argument)
  error • Undefined name 'internalLocatorFn' at lib/main.data.dart:52:9 • (undefined_identifier)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'provider' at lib/main.data.dart:52:30 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'context' at lib/main.data.dart:52:40 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • The name 'ProviderContainer' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument at lib/main.data.dart:53:27 • (non_type_as_type_argument)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic method 'map<K2, V2>' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_grocery_item/add_grocery_item_form_entity.g.dart:15:77 • (implicit_dynamic_method)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'k' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_grocery_item/add_grocery_item_form_entity.g.dart:16:14 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'e' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_grocery_item/add_grocery_item_form_entity.g.dart:16:17 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic type 'MapEntry<String, dynamic>' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_grocery_item/add_grocery_item_form_entity.g.dart:16:23 • (implicit_dynamic_type)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic method 'map<K2, V2>' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_grocery_item/add_grocery_item_form_entity.g.dart:20:74 • (implicit_dynamic_method)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'k' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_grocery_item/add_grocery_item_form_entity.g.dart:21:14 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'e' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_grocery_item/add_grocery_item_form_entity.g.dart:21:17 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic type 'MapEntry<String, dynamic>' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_grocery_item/add_grocery_item_form_entity.g.dart:21:23 • (implicit_dynamic_type)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic method 'map<K2, V2>' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:18:77 • (implicit_dynamic_method)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'k' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:19:14 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'e' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:19:17 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic type 'MapEntry<String, dynamic>' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:19:23 • (implicit_dynamic_type)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic method 'map<K2, V2>' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:23:75 • (implicit_dynamic_method)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'k' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:24:14 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'e' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:24:17 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic type 'MapEntry<String, dynamic>' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:24:23 • (implicit_dynamic_type)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'e' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:30:16 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic method 'map<K2, V2>' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:32:55 • (implicit_dynamic_method)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'k' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:33:18 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'e' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:33:21 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic type 'MapEntry<String, dynamic>' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:33:27 • (implicit_dynamic_type)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'e' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:37:16 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic method 'map<K2, V2>' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:39:55 • (implicit_dynamic_method)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'k' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:40:18 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'e' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:40:21 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic type 'MapEntry<String, dynamic>' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/add_vegan_item/add_vegan_item_form_entity.g.dart:40:27 • (implicit_dynamic_type)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic method 'map<K2, V2>' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/user_registration/user_registration_form_entity.g.dart:20:47 • (implicit_dynamic_method)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'k' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/user_registration/user_registration_form_entity.g.dart:21:14 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'e' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/user_registration/user_registration_form_entity.g.dart:21:17 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic type 'MapEntry<String, dynamic>' at lib/src/application/entities/forms/user_registration/user_registration_form_entity.g.dart:21:23 • (implicit_dynamic_type)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'e' at lib/src/application/entities/search_params/establishments/establishments_search_params_entity.g.dart:20:44 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'e' at lib/src/domain/entities/vegan_item/grocery_item/grocery_item_domain_entity.g.dart:19:16 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic method 'map<K2, V2>' at lib/src/domain/entities/vegan_item/grocery_item/grocery_item_domain_entity.g.dart:21:55 • (implicit_dynamic_method)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'k' at lib/src/domain/entities/vegan_item/grocery_item/grocery_item_domain_entity.g.dart:22:18 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'e' at lib/src/domain/entities/vegan_item/grocery_item/grocery_item_domain_entity.g.dart:22:21 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic type 'MapEntry<String, dynamic>' at lib/src/domain/entities/vegan_item/grocery_item/grocery_item_domain_entity.g.dart:22:27 • (implicit_dynamic_type)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic method 'map<K2, V2>' at lib/src/domain/entities/vegan_item/menu_item/menu_item_domain_entity.g.dart:17:75 • (implicit_dynamic_method)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'k' at lib/src/domain/entities/vegan_item/menu_item/menu_item_domain_entity.g.dart:18:14 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'e' at lib/src/domain/entities/vegan_item/menu_item/menu_item_domain_entity.g.dart:18:17 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic type 'MapEntry<String, dynamic>' at lib/src/domain/entities/vegan_item/menu_item/menu_item_domain_entity.g.dart:18:23 • (implicit_dynamic_type)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'e' at lib/src/domain/entities/vegan_item/menu_item/menu_item_domain_entity.g.dart:24:16 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic method 'map<K2, V2>' at lib/src/domain/entities/vegan_item/menu_item/menu_item_domain_entity.g.dart:26:55 • (implicit_dynamic_method)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'k' at lib/src/domain/entities/vegan_item/menu_item/menu_item_domain_entity.g.dart:27:18 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing parameter type for 'e' at lib/src/domain/entities/vegan_item/menu_item/menu_item_domain_entity.g.dart:27:21 • (implicit_dynamic_parameter)
  error • Missing type arguments for generic type 'MapEntry<String, dynamic>' at lib/src/domain/entities/vegan_item/menu_item/menu_item_domain_entity.g.dart:27:27 • (implicit_dynamic_type)
  error • The method '_$_$_SelectListItemFromJson' isn't defined for the type '_$_SelectListItem' at lib/src/presentation/widgets/form_fields/select_fields/common/select_list_item/select_list_item.freezed.dart:116:7 • (undefined_method)
  error • A value of type 'dynamic' can't be returned from constructor '_$_SelectListItem.fromJson' because it has a return type of '_$_SelectListItem' at lib/src/presentation/widgets/form_fields/select_fields/common/select_list_item/select_list_item.freezed.dart:116:7 • (return_of_invalid_type)
  error • The method '_$_$_SelectListItemToJson' isn't defined for the type '_$_SelectListItem' at lib/src/presentation/widgets/form_fields/select_fields/common/select_list_item/select_list_item.freezed.dart:151:12 • (undefined_method)
  error • A value of type 'dynamic' can't be returned from method 'toJson' because it has a return type of 'Map<String, dynamic>' at lib/src/presentation/widgets/form_fields/select_fields/common/select_list_item/select_list_item.freezed.dart:151:12 • (return_of_invalid_type)
```

my flutter doctor:

```
benjaminfarquhar@Benjamins-MacBook-Pro vepo_front_end % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on macOS 11.2.1 20D74 darwin-x64, locale en-NZ)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
[✓] Connected device (5 available)
```

I tried running it with `--ignore-errors` but it still had an exception:

```
Generating migration suggestions...
[-                                                                                                                             [\                                                                                                                             [|                                                                                                                             [---                                                                                                                          ]Aborting migration due to an exception.  This may be due to a bug in
the migration tool, or it may be due to errors in the source code
being migrated.  If possible, try to fix errors in the source code and
re-try migrating.  If that doesn't work, consider filing a bug report
at:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/new
To attempt to perform migration anyway, you may re-run with
--ignore-exceptions.

Exception details:

Bad state: Missing declarated type annotation in /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/lib/main.data.dart; for String

#0      Variables.decoratedTypeAnnotation (package:nnbd_migration/src/variables.dart:113:7)
#1      EdgeBuilder.visitTypeName (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:1729:26)
#2      TypeNameImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:10141:49)
#3      EdgeBuilder._dispatch (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:2104:22)
#4      EdgeBuilder.visitNode (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:1258:9)
#5      GeneralizingAstVisitor.visitTypeArgumentList (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:564:53)
#6      TypeArgumentListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:10022:49)
#7      TypeNameImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:10146:21)
#8      EdgeBuilder.visitTypeName (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:1764:16)
#9      TypeNameImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:10141:49)
#10     EdgeBuilder._dispatch (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:2104:22)
#11     EdgeBuilder.visitNode (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:1258:9)
#12     GeneralizingAstVisitor.visitFormalParameter (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:306:51)
#13     GeneralizingAstVisitor.visitNormalFormalParameter (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:450:7)
#14     GeneralizingAstVisitor.visitSimpleFormalParameter (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:502:7)
#15     SimpleFormalParameterImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:8793:15)
#16     EdgeBuilder._dispatch (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:2104:22)
#17     EdgeBuilder.visitDefaultFormalParameter (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:719:5)
#18     DefaultFormalParameterImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:2987:15)
#19     EdgeBuilder._dispatch (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:2104:22)
#20     EdgeBuilder.visitNode (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:1258:9)
#21     GeneralizingAstVisitor.visitFormalParameterList (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:309:59)
#22     FormalParameterListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:4449:49)
#23     EdgeBuilder._dispatch (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:2104:22)
#24     EdgeBuilder.visitFunctionExpression (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:865:5)
#25     FunctionExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:4963:49)
#26     EdgeBuilder._dispatch (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:2104:22)
#27     EdgeBuilder._handleAssignment (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:2218:20)
#28     EdgeBuilder.visitVariableDeclarationList (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:1834:11)
#29     VariableDeclarationListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:10575:15)
#30     EdgeBuilder._dispatch (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:2104:22)
#31     EdgeBuilder.visitNode (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:1258:9)
#32     GeneralizingAstVisitor.visitAnnotatedNode (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:137:47)
#33     GeneralizingAstVisitor.visitDeclaration (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:230:43)
#34     GeneralizingAstVisitor.visitCompilationUnitMember (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:205:7)
#35     GeneralizingAstVisitor.visitTopLevelVariableDeclaration (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:554:7)
#36     TopLevelVariableDeclarationImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:9840:15)
#37     EdgeBuilder._dispatch (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:2104:22)
#38     EdgeBuilder.visitNode (package:nnbd_migration/src/edge_builder.dart:1258:9)
#39     GeneralizingAstVisitor.visitCompilationUnit (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:202:51)
#40     CompletenessTracker.visitCompilationUnit.<anonymous closure> (package:nnbd_migration/src/utilities/completeness_tracker.dart:52:24)
#41     PermissiveModeVisitor.reportExceptionsIfPermissive (package:nnbd_migration/src/utilities/permissive_mode.dart:26:24)
#42     CompletenessTracker.visitCompilationUnit (package:nnbd_migration/src/utilities/completeness_tracker.dart:43:5)
#43     CompilationUnitImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:2119:49)
#44     NullabilityMigrationImpl.processInput (package:nnbd_migration/src/nullability_migration_impl.dart:190:12)
#45     NonNullableFix.processUnit (package:nnbd_migration/src/front_end/non_nullable_fix.dart:159:15)
#46     _FixCodeProcessor.runLaterPhases.<anonymous closure> (package:nnbd_migration/migration_cli.dart:1023:19)
#47     _FixCodeProcessor.processResources (package:nnbd_migration/migration_cli.dart:967:30)
<asynchronous suspension>
#48     _FixCodeProcessor.runLaterPhases (package:nnbd_migration/migration_cli.dart:1021:11)
#49     MigrationCliRunner.run (package:nnbd_migration/migration_cli.dart:610:43)
<asynchronous suspension>
#50     MigrateCommand.run (package:nnbd_migration/migration_cli.dart:204:72)
#51     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:27)
#52     DartdevRunner.runCommand (package:dartdev/dartdev.dart:324:24)
#53     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:25)
#54     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:223:31)
#55     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:14)
#56     runDartdev (package:dartdev/dartdev.dart:143:27)
#57     main (file:///b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/dartdev/bin/dartdev.dart:11:9)
#58     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:32)
#59     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

How can I get `dart migrate` to work even though I'm using code gen?

Answer (score 0):

Same here, but we could edit it manually, I know even though the package support nullsafety, we still got this error

Known issues
Not all parts of the Flutter SDK support null safety yet, as some parts still need additional work to migrate to null safety.

We’re currently aware of the following issues:

Migration of the pub.dev packages owned by the Flutter team is in progress. See pub.dev for the current list. We expect the majority of packages to be migrated in the coming weeks; the only exceptions we expect are the legacy integration_tests package, which is deprecated in favor of the version in the Flutter SDK itself (though see below), and some of the packages in https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/master/packages which may take longer to be migrated.

Integration testing with flutter_driver and the version of integration_test in the Flutter SDK.

Currently, these methods do not support null safety on the host side of the test. You can drive a null-safe application, but the test itself will not use null-safe Dart.
Depending on these packages (flutter_driver and integration_test) will limit your ability to pick up some already migrated dependencies such as args, archive, and crypto, since these packages themselves depend on the non-migrated versions.
We expect to have this resolved in the first half of 2021.

If you are interested in seeing the latest updates before they reach the beta and stable branches, and are willing to live on the bleeding edge, consider using dev builds (flutter channel dev).